# how to download base 64 image into png, ppt and pdf in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to download base 64 data into ppt and pdf format.

```
    var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#image'));
    var val = myEl.append($compile('<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' + 
    $scope.Image + '"/>')($scope));
    console.log(val)
```

This is the code which convert base 64 to image

Thanks in advance

Comment: view it in your browser, right click, save as

Comment: i want to download the image in png format

Answer (score 0):

You can use some online APIs like [rethumb](https://rethumb.com/)